# How to get specific system tray icon using pywinauto?

Tags: python, ui-automation, pywinauto

For example the Slack icon from the notification area:

[image: slack example icon]

And how can we get a specific icon in case of "show hidden" icons option?

Comment: What's the problem to edit this question? They both of low quality. pywinauto has module `pywinauto.taskbar`. Is it failing? If yes, what is your code and the error output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me,

## If your app icon are visible on taskbar

```
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path="explorer.exe")
sys_tray = app.window(class_name="Shell_TrayWnd")
sys_tray.child_window(title=<your icon>).click()
```

## In-case application icon which in hidden tray

```
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path="explorer.exe")
st = app.window(class_name="Shell_TrayWnd")
t = st.child_window(title="Notification Chevron").wrapper_object()
t.click()

# Handle notify icon  overflow window

list_box = Application(backend="uia").connect(class_name="NotifyIconOverflowWindow")
list_box_win = list_box.window(class_name="NotifyIconOverflowWindow")
list_box_win.wait('visible', timeout=30, retry_interval=3)

# Select required option from drop-down 

ddm = desk.create_window(best_match="DropDownMenu")
desk.wait_for_window_to_appear(ddm, wait_for='ready', timeout=20, retry_interval=2)
ddm.child_window(title=<select option>, control_type="MenuItem").click_input()
```

Comment: I've got an error: NameError: name 'desk' is not defined.

Comment: is the above code still valid for Windows 10? because, this is no able to fine `NotifyIconOverflowWindow`

Comment: where do you take params like : .click() ?  on page pyautogui. docs ?

Answer (score 2):

User this code ( Modified [sunil-kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9787892/sunil-kumar) code  )

```
from pywinauto import Application
import time

app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path="explorer.exe")
st = app.window(class_name="Shell_TrayWnd")
t = st.child_window(title="Notification Chevron").wrapper_object()
t.click()

time.sleep(0.25)

list_box = Application(backend="uia").connect(class_name="NotifyIconOverflowWindow")
list_box_win = list_box.window(class_name="NotifyIconOverflowWindow")
list_box_win.wait('visible', timeout=30, retry_interval=3)

list_box_win.child_window(title="APPLICATION NAME").click()
```