# Is there way to handle system tray icon window over dropdown window

Tags: ui-automation, pywinauto

[How to access/use the window which is underneath another window upon it, please click on the link to check this case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2LIL.png)

I'm using pywinauto to do this, is there a way to handle this case/issue.

**Issue:**

1. By following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50464576/how-to-get-specific-system-tray-icon-using-pywinauto/50560105#50560105), able to open system tray and click on the icon, which results in drop-down menu.
2. But when i try to mover over mouse to click specific option from drop-down, hidden icons window re-appears on top of the drop-down list, which results in wrong click.
3. Is there a way to handle these windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get specific system tray icon using pywinauto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50464576/how-to-get-specific-system-tray-icon-using-pywinauto)

Comment: Hi Vasily, that question is different than this, where here  the case is that after clicking the icon --> drop-down appears ---> while clicking the specific item in drop-down list, seeing `hidden icons` window appeared again upon dropdown window as seen in the screenshot. which turns out to be click on wrong object.